# Fire Observable bindCallback multiple times

Tags: javascript, observable

I have an api which fires an event on a callback every once in a while:

```
api(params, (error, result) =>
  console.log('PUBSUB', result)
);
```

which means I see in the console.log multiples logs of this api result.

I wish to use an Observable to do this

```
const obs = Observable.bindNodeCallback((params, callback) =>
  api(params, callback)
);

obs.subscribe(data => console.log('OBSERVABLE', data));
```

I only see one console.log. It's related to https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1401, but I cannot find a way to make it fire multiple times.

Comment: I've added the [reactjs] tag, I guess that's correct?

Comment: I am using react, but this question is not related to react.

Comment: As far as I know is anything regarding observables not part of the core JS language, so it seems definitely related.

Comment: Observable can be used anywhere, it is not related to react. I am using it in Angular 4 with TypeScript so..

Comment: "not part of the core JS language" -> What do you mean?

Comment: @amaurymartiny Can you point out the part of the JS spec that covers `Observable.bindNodeCallback` and all the other APIs you are using here? I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally went with something along these lines:

```
  const obs = params => Observable.create(observer => {
    api(params, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        observer.error(error);
      } else {
        observer.next(result);
      }
    });
  });
```

If anybody has a better idea I'll be glad to change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

rxjs is very confusing in the beginning. You are better off creating a `Subject`, then creating an `Observable` which other methods can `subscribe` to

```
const testData = {myParam: ["param1", "param2"], callback: myCallback};

const callbackSubject = new Subject();
const callbackObservable = callbackSubject.asObservable();

callbackObservable.subscribe(data => console.log(data));

callbackSubject.next(testData); // subscribe is called
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but it may help somebody: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/fromEventPattern

```
Observable.fromEventPattern(
  (handler) => {
    // unsubscribtion can be returned
    return api(params, (error, result) => {
      // handle errors
      handler(result)
    })
  },
  (handler, unsubscribe) => { unsubscribe(); }
)
```